# Removing elements in list that appear in dict

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

Hello everyone I tried doing this:

```
public List<DirectoryInfo> RemoveDuplicates()
    {
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DirectoryInfo>> entry in b)
      {
        var wtf = a.RemoveAll(x => entry.Value.Contains(x) && x.Parent.Name == entry.Key);
      }

      return a;
    }
```

It's supposed to be a function that tells remove duplicates in my original list of DirectoryInfos that are in my dictionary B. I want to do this by comparing the name and parent name of list A with the Parent (keys) and list of subfolders (values) in my dict. My list A actually is a list of DirectoryInfos but its all the subfolders so it remembers its name and knows its parent. For the dictionnary I'm trying to ask in the for loop to remove every parent name that appear in a remove it. I tried doing this and checking the value of "wtf" and it says 0.

***EDIT***

List a contains items => 9.4.3.4 (this is x or x.name), ACE (this is x.parent name an example of a parent name)

Dictionnary B => contains this exactly if I go in debug

```
[0] {[Name="IG"-Version="6_6", System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>>
```

so inside of the [0] POSITION the key contains =

```
Key "Name=\"IG\"-Version=\"6_6\""   string
```

and in the value we have a list of subfolders ill show u how one name looks like.
+

```
[0] {6.6.1.107_8}   System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

So im trying to see if there is a key that matchers with a parent name in list a check if we have any of the same folders inside. remove them

*********EDIT 2*******

So this is going to be an example of something I want to remove in list a that appears in dictionary b. So originally we parsed a xml file of this format:

```
<Asset Name="SGL" Version="9.6">
      <TestCase Name="sst" Version="9.6.1.111" SubVersion=""/>
    </Asset>
```

Which we then store in a dictionary like so:

```
Key "Name=\"SGL\"-Version=\"9_6\""  string


[0] {9.6.1.111} System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

where we tryin to compare in a list a if it contains the same thing list a looks like this:

9.6.1.111 (it contains the name of folder) but it knows its parent also (SLG_9_6)

Comment: 1) Are you sure there are duplicates that actually need to be removed? 2) Your question really isn't clear - perhaps if you have an example of what would be in `a` and `b` (and please use better variable names) and what you'd expect the output to be?

Comment: I think youi logic is backwards.  There is no need to enumerate through dictionary.  You simply want to enumerate through your list and produce output using WHERE and item doesn't appear in the dictionary.  Use the dictionary CONTAINS method.

Comment: 100% there are duplicates I'll add more at the bottom of my original post expected input/output

Comment: @jdweng: It's a little hard to parse the question, but I think what they are doing is a bit more complicated. The dictionary is `Dictionary<string,List<DirectoryInfo>>` and the list is just `List<DirectoryInfo>`. They want to check if a `DirectoryInfo` from `a` exists in any of the lists in `b` where the parent of the item in `a` is the key in `b`. Either way, they shouldn't need to loop through the dictionary.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of yesterday's question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686076/compare-sets-of-two-strings-that-are-in-different-format-dictionary-vs-listdire. Please do not double-post.

Comment: i edited my question on top for more clarity of what is going on

Comment: If the parent (according to you last edit) of `a[0]` is `SLG_9_6` then that clearly *does not* match the key in your dictionary of `Name="SGL"-Version="9_6"` - so that's your problem. You can't match a key if *it doesn't actually match!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to loop through the dictionary and it would be inefficient to do so. All you should need is something like:

```
var wtf = a.RemoveAll(x => b.ContainsKey(x.Parent.Name) && b[x.Parent.Name].Contains(x));
```

So you check if `b` contains the `Parent.Name` and if it does, then you check to see if the list for *that entry only* contains `x`.

Having said that, I'm not sure your original code shouldn't have worked anyway - so your actual problem might be somewhere else.

Your problem might actually come from the `Contains` part. Since `DirectoryInfo` is a class, it will do reference equality for `Contains`. In other words, it will only work if you have references *to the same object* in `a` and `b`. If they are not the same, then you will have to compare the values.

Something like:

```
var wtf = a.RemoveAll(x => b.ContainsKey(x.Parent.Name) &&
          b[x.Parent.Name].Any(y => y.FullName == x.FullName));
```

Assuming that comparing the `FullName` of two `DirectoryInfo` objects is what you wanted

Comment: i dont think this would work because doing b[x.Parent.Name] i dont think thats how u identify different dictionnary values is it? Also I do not want to compare full name as it doesn't have the same root path just the name and parent name are the same

Comment: @PhillipsJP: Of course it is. You are supplying the key (`Name`) and retrieving the list. That's what `Dictionary` is for.

Comment: @PhillipsJP: *"Also I do not want to compare full name"* then don't. Substitute `Name` instead.

Comment: ok but did you see my edit in the main post of how it is displayed in the debug ? I don't understand the syntax b[x.parent.name] could you explain?

Comment: my var still contains 0 after trying both of your solutions

Comment: [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx). In the data you gave in your question, there are no duplicates because nothing in your list matches the key in the dictionary

Comment: Can i show you an example of a how a duplicate looks like? and then we can work on that?

Comment: @PhillipsJP: Your keys don't match

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: What's to explain? `Name="SGL"-Version="9_6"` != `SLG_9_6`

Comment: how do I fix that ? first of its SGL-9_6 in the list a

Comment: @PhillipsJP: *By making them **match***. Either you need to change the keys in your dictionary to match the format you use for the directories or you need to parse your directory names (`x.Parent.Name`) into a format that matches the format you use the keys. The first option is *probably* easier

Comment: but what I dont get when I call b.containskey does it return literally Name="SGL"-Version="9_6" as the name like i dont understand why its stored that way it should just be SGL-9_6

Comment: this is how i stored it in the xml converter

Comment: string branchName = asset.Attribute("Name").ToString();

Comment: in debug it looks like this branchName = "Name=\"IG\"" If i just want IG and not all the crap around it how do I do that